# Communicate between Liferay portlet and Android application through websocket which run in Liferay Portal

Tags: websocket, liferay, chat, portlet

My goal is user can chat between portlet and Android app.
Can I create a portlet or something which include websocket run automatically when it is actived in Liferay portal? 
How can i run class socketserver.java automatically:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class SocketServer {

// set to store all the live sessions
private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections
        .synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

// Mapping between session and person name
private static final HashMap<String, String> nameSessionPair = new HashMap<String, String>();

private JSONUtils jsonUtils = new JSONUtils();

// Getting query params
public static Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
    Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    if (query != null) {
        String[] params = query.split("&");
        for (String param : params) {
            String[] nameval = param.split("=");
            map.put(nameval[0], nameval[1]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

/**
 * Called when a socket connection opened
 * */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {

    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");

    Map<String, String> queryParams = getQueryMap(session.getQueryString());

    String name = "";

    if (queryParams.containsKey("name")) {

        // Getting client name via query param
        name = queryParams.get("name");
        try {
            name = URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Mapping client name and session id
        nameSessionPair.put(session.getId(), name);
    }

    // Adding session to session list
    sessions.add(session);

    try {
        // Sending session id to the client that just connected
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(
                jsonUtils.getClientDetailsJson(session.getId(),
                        "Your session details"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Notifying all the clients about new person joined
    sendMessageToAll(session.getId(), name, " joined conversation!", true,
            false);

}

/**
 * method called when new message received from any client
 * 
 * @param message
 *            JSON message from client
 * */
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {

    System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);

    String msg = null;

    // Parsing the json and getting message
    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(message);
        msg = jObj.getString("message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Sending the message to all clients
    sendMessageToAll(session.getId(), nameSessionPair.get(session.getId()),
            msg, false, false);
}

/**
 * Method called when a connection is closed
 * */
@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session) {

    System.out.println("Session " + session.getId() + " has ended");

    // Getting the client name that exited
    String name = nameSessionPair.get(session.getId());

    // removing the session from sessions list
    sessions.remove(session);

    // Notifying all the clients about person exit
    sendMessageToAll(session.getId(), name, " left conversation!", false,
            true);

}

/**
 * Method to send message to all clients
 * 
 * @param sessionId
 * @param message
 *            message to be sent to clients
 * @param isNewClient
 *            flag to identify that message is about new person joined
 * @param isExit
 *            flag to identify that a person left the conversation
 * */
private void sendMessageToAll(String sessionId, String name,
        String message, boolean isNewClient, boolean isExit) {

    // Looping through all the sessions and sending the message individually
    for (Session s : sessions) {
        String json = null;

        // Checking if the message is about new client joined
        if (isNewClient) {
            json = jsonUtils.getNewClientJson(sessionId, name, message,
                    sessions.size());

        } else if (isExit) {
            // Checking if the person left the conversation
            json = jsonUtils.getClientExitJson(sessionId, name, message,
                    sessions.size());
        } else {
            // Normal chat conversation message
            json = jsonUtils
                    .getSendAllMessageJson(sessionId, name, message);
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Sending Message To: " + sessionId + ", "
                    + json);

            s.getBasicRemote().sendText(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error in sending. " + s.getId() + ", "
                    + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Following this tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/
Any ideals what i resolve that?

I read this blog https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/liferay-websockets-and-node-good-times- talk about websocket but the sample is not run correctly.

Comment: Have you considered using Liferay Screens? https://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-screens